# $scope variable passing from one function to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular controller's function looks like:

```
$scope.selectinteresteduser= function(Id){
   $scope.selecteduserid=Id;
}
$scope.sendMessageToEmployeer = function($scope.selecteduserid) {

   alert($scope.selecteduserid);
}
```

I want to pass the value of $scope.selecteduserid to sendMessageToEmployer function. How to do it?

Comment: I think you should first know the fundamentals of javascript before delving in angular

Comment: can you Please help me with related link..?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript have fun coding! :)

Comment: Ok.. Actually the problem was , I haven't clean my tomcat server. Actually it was a working code... :/   BTW thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $scope specifies that you can access its elements globally in your controller. 
You can access it directly as $scope.selecteduserid
No need to pass it as argument. Please improve the basics.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the id in as an argument to the function by defining and calling the function as follows:

```
$scope.sendMessageToEmployeer = function(id) {
   alert(id);
}

$scope.sendMessageToEmployeer($scope.selecteduserid);
```

Comment: Listen i am calling sendMessageToEmployer function from view ..  I want function like :   $scope.sendMessageToEmployer(){ // Here $scope.toUserId=$scope.selecteduserid //some logic }.. @PaulFitgerald

Answer (score 1):

No need to pass it as argument. `selecteduserid` is already available across all functions in your controller.

```
$scope.sendMessageToEmployeer = function() {
   alert($scope.selecteduserid);
}

// execute function
$scope.sendMessageToEmployeer();
```

If you need to call the function from the **template**, do it like this;

```
$scope.sendMessageToEmployeer = function(id) {
   alert(id);
}
```

On Template

```
<button type="button" ng-click="sendMessageToEmployeer(selecteduserid)"></button>
```

Please read Angular Documentation, Specially **Angular Concept** if you want to learn. @ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts.